# java - return object value

Tags: java, object

Hi i have the following code:

```
public List<Person> findAll() {

    List<Person> copy = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (Person person : personer) {
        copy.add(person);
    }

    return copy;

}
```

But when i test this i only retrieve the following and not the value:

> [Person@15c7850, Person@1ded0fd,
>   Person@16a9d42]

How do i get the values and not like above. Where i am inserting the person the code looks like this:

```
public boolean insert(String name, String nbr) {

    if (containsName(name)) {
                    return false;
            }
    Person person = new Person(name, nbr);
    personer.add(person);

            return true;
}
```

and here is my Person class:

```
class Person {

private String name;
private String nbr;





public Person (String name, String nbr) {
    this.name = name;
    this.nbr = nbr;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public String getNumber() {
    return nbr;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "values"? Is there some field on the person class that you are expecting to see?

Comment: i have in the list saved the name and the telephone number of the person... i want to show that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already receiving the objects you want.

What you see is an internal representation of these objects.

You must iterate through them and call their respective methods to see the information you probably want to see.

If you're not satisfied with these results, you must override `toString` to provide you with more meaningful information.

**Update**:

after seeing your edit, you should add `toString` similar to this one in your `Person` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + ", number: " + nbr; 
}
```

By the way, you're storing `nbr` as a string, and it's obvious it should be an integer. So, I'd suggest changing its type to an `int` or `Integer`.

Comment: @Jake: `toString()` will show you a "default" value. Since Java doesn't know anything about context of your class, it will just print its internal representation of your class. As I said, you must override `toString` to show you what you really want. Although Java tries to be smart, it cannot always guess your intentions.

Comment: go to Person class and create a new toString method, there you can return for example: return "Name" + this.name; Do that to all attributes you got on your class in a single String to return meaningful information as @darioo said.

Comment: I added some more information in my question above. That is how i am inserting the person.

Comment: @Jake: your newly added code won't help us much. You should also show us your `Person` class.

Comment: This is only a good idea if you are looking to print something.  If you actually want to use the values, you have to do something else in the context of what is going on here.  It is pretty much useless if you want to do things like Person lookups via name/number.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a List object back.  You can use the Person object to get the data that you need.  To get to the Person objects, iterate over the list.

```
List<Person> people = findAll();
for Person p : people {
    String phoneNumber = p.phoneNumber();
    String name = p.Name();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the toString() method in the Person class if you want a better description when printing the results.

Answer (score 1):

Put something like this in the class `Person` (don't change the method name!):

```
public String toString() {
    return name;//change this line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out an Object that has the default toString inherited from the Object class. This will print out the type of object it is and its location in memory (ie: Person@1ded0fd).

If you'd like it to see something else, you can override the toString method within your class:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;

  public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }    

  public String toString() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

If your class looked like the above, this would allow you to do something like this:

```
Person p = new Person("John");
System.out.println(p);
 > John
```

You can also just grab it as is and print out any information you want from it without overriding the toString method.

```
Person p = new Person("John");
System.out.println(p.getName());
 > John
```

Answer (score 0):

What value or class Person's property you aspect to retrieve from the ArrayList? This kind of value(Person@15c7850, etc) shows that the Person's object random id that assigned by JVM when you use

`System.out.print(copy)`.

Comment: It's not random; it's the address of the reference.